# Nestjs/microservice does not create an observable?

Tags: node.js, rxjs, protocol-buffers, grpc, nestjs

I was trying to use streams with grpc.
But when I use the below-published code, it says that subscribe is not a function. 
It seems like nestjs/microservice does not create an observable from a stream.
The method used in the docs seems to be outdated.

My code - proto file:

```
message Rating {
  string id = 1;
  uint32 value = 2;
  string comment = 3;
  string type = 4;
}

service RatingsRpcService {
  rpc Test (stream GetRatingRequest) returns (stream Rating);
}

message GetRatingRequest {
  string id = 1;
}

message Ratings {
  repeated Rating items = 1;
}
```

And the controller file:

```
    @GrpcStreamMethod('RatingsRpcService')
    test(msg: Observable<any>, metadata: any): Observable<any> {
        const subject = new Subject();
        msg.subscribe({
            next: (item: any) => {
                subject.next({whatever: 'value'});
            },
            error: (err: any) => console.log(err),
            complete: () => subject.complete()
        });
        return subject.asObservable();
    }
```

And the error I get: TypeError: msg.subscribe is not a function
Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I guess I found the issue.
It's kinda strange, but changing the type from Observable fixed the error.
I mean this one: `messages: any` instead of messages: `Observable<any>` or messages: `Observable<RatingInterface>`.
Please find the code presented below:

```
@GrpcStreamMethod('RatingsRpcService')
async findByIdStream(messages: any, metadata: any): Promise<Observable<RatingInterface>> {
    const subject = new Subject<RatingInterface>();
    messages.subscribe({
        next: async (dto: GetRatingDto) => {
            const item = await this.ratingsService.findById(dto.id);
            subject.next(item);
        },
        error: (err: any) => {
            throw new RpcException('Could not process stream.')
        },
        complete: () => subject.complete()
    });

    return subject.asObservable();
}
```

Comment: `Promise<Observable<RatingInterface>>` looks a bit strange to me. Don't you get any type errors for this?

Comment: @AndreiGătej No, what strange about it? It's actually correct TS syntax, at least as far as I know

Comment: Is there a need to return a promise? Won't an Observable alone suffice?

Comment: @DerrylThomas I don't think so, because this.ratingsService.findById(dto.id) returns a promise

Comment: I am no rxjs expert, but is it not possible to get an observable from the promise and pipe it to the response?

Comment: I'm also not a rxjs expert, however, the above-published solution works for me. The error I got is somehow connected to nestjs/microservices bundle, because when I change the variable type, it started to work.